# Is Blue exorcist really based on a slush puppy?

Tags: blue-exorcist

During a discussion with some friends, one of my friends said that blue exorcist is based on a slush puppy. I know some artists can get creative through a lot of things (elfen lied from a German poem) but I found this one pretty hard to believe.

[image]

Hence my question: Is blue exorcist really based on this slush puppy? Or on something else?

Comment: This seems both 1.) obviously wrong and 2.) very difficult to disprove. I very much doubt that there will be any source that says "Blue Exorcist was not based on an ice-slush beverage".

Comment: @senshin loopers answer might not disagree tot he beverage but does show he based it with other ideals in mind

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In an interview with Animenewsnetwork, he said that he was inspired by a Grimm fairy tale:

> **What were your chief inspirations when creating Blue Exorcist?**
>
> **Kato:** It originally was inspired by a Brothers Grimm fairy tale, where brothers combat monsters.  Then, I tried to make the story flip several times, and settled down into a simple structure of demons versus an exorcist.

[Source](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/interview/2011-04-08/interview-blue-exorcist-mangaka-kazue-kato)